# R : How to control the right click of mouse in gWidgets

Tags: r, user-interface, tk-toolkit, gwidgets

In gWidget GUI I have seen a feature on right click on mouse

1. Copy
2. Save

How can I use that Save handler so save my shown dataset in table ?
Kindly refer to the image below :
[image]

Also in my code I have used graphicspane1 <- **ggraphics(cont = group1)**

Kindly suggest answers ASAP

Here is a sample code,

```
 library(cairoDevice)
 library(gWidgets)
 library(gWidgetsRGtk2)
 require(RGtk2)

 fun <- function(){
    tbl <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3),X=c('A','B','C'))
    grid.draw(tableGrob(tbl, gp=gpar(fontsize=8, lwd=1.2)))
  }

  options(guiToolkit = "RGtk2")
  w        <-gwindow("GUI")
  g        <-ggroup(cont=w)
  plotbutton4 <- gbutton('Draw Table', cont = g, handler=function(h,...){
  fun()})
 graphic1 <- ggraphics(cont=g)
```

Steps : 1. Click on the button "Draw Table"
Step  : 2. Right Click and try to save the data.

How can I make a relation with that Save & Copy Button, more focus on SAVE

Comment: You should include some code.

Comment: @Thomas Here I have do some coding as a demo, kindly help if possible

Comment: Look at `addHandlerRightclick`.

Comment: You also have to disable the built-in popup (passing `no_popup=TRUE`). Also, add3rdMousePopupmenu might be better.

Comment: I have already used that no_popup=TRUE, need to get the current table data and save it into CSV, or any other format